# Can dimension jumping fiber be irreducible non-reduced?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, complex-geometry

Let $X,Y$ be complex algebraic manifolds. Let $f\colon X\to Y$ be a proper surjective morphism, with all geometric fibers irreducible. Suppose that for some $y\in Y$, the inverse $f^{-1}(y)$ satisfy $\mathrm{dim}f^{-1}(y)>\mathrm{dim}X-\mathrm{dim}Y$, can $f^{-1}(y)$ be non-reduced?

[The previous version of this question asks whether $f$ necessarily gives a surjection $TX\to TY$ of tangent bundles, and it pointed out in the comments that this can fail.]

Comment: No, that is not true.  Consider the case of an elliptic fibration with an everywhere nonreduced fiber whose associated reduced fiber is an elliptic curve.

Comment: @JasonStarr I am a bit confused... should the general fiber be smooth, by the smoothness assumption of $X,Y$?

Comment: Yes, the general fiber should be smooth.  There is a classification of elliptic fibrations by Kodaira.

Comment: @JasonStarr Thanks! Would there be a chance that the induced map $Tf\colon T_Y|_{f^{-1}(y)}\to T_yY$ be surjection if we ask the special fiber $f^{-1}(y)$ has strictly higher dimension than all the other fibers? In this case, will the special fiber be forced to be reduced?

Comment: Sure - blow up a point, or a nonsingular subvariety.

Comment: @Qixiao : by "manifolds" you mean smooth, don't you? You do want to exclude the case where $Y$ is singular?

Comment: @Libli Yes, the original question I had in mind would like to have the base being smooth

Comment: @pinaki Yes, thanks! We would ask the special fiber be irreducible. (I also guessed that the special fiber being reduced at some point $x$ would imply surjection of tangent spaces $T_xX\to T_yY$, and your comment shows that this is could fail.)

Comment: Take a surface $S$ with a fibration onto a curve $C$ with a multiple fiber $F$, take the product fibration $S\times S\rightarrow C\times C$, and blow up $F\times F$.

Comment: @abx Thanks! (And in this example the tangent bundle $T_X$ does not surject onto $T_Y$ and answers my original question.)